# ojAlog - ConvexSolver in Kotlin: 2d Array

Tags: kotlin, convex-optimization, ojalgo

I'm trying to implement some example as I am planning to explore ojAlgo for optimization purposes. 
My question is really simple.

In Java I can easily write:

```
PrimitiveDenseStore Q = PrimitiveDenseStore.FACTORY.rows(new double[][]{{2.0,0.0}, {0.0, 2.0}});
```

I tried to do the same thing it kotlin:

```
val Q: Array<DoubleArray> = arrayOf(DoubleArray(2.0, 0.0), DoubleArray(2.0, 0.0))
var tmpQ = PrimitiveDenseStore.FACTORY.rows(Q)
```

but it seems that .rows cannot be called with the argument I gave.

Maybe I doing something stupid but I would appreciate the help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DoubleArray` constructor takes array size as a first argument, that's why your construction is invalid. The analogue of `double[][]` in Kotlin is `Array<DoubleArray>`, that's right, but it should be constructed like this:

```
val Q: Array<DoubleArray> = arrayOf(doubleArrayOf(2.0, 0.0), doubleArrayOf(2.0, 0.0))
```

**UPDATE:**

Looks like `rows` function takes `double[]... source` as params, so in Kotlin you can use spread operator:

```
val Q: Array<DoubleArray> = arrayOf(doubleArrayOf(2.0, 0.0), doubleArrayOf(2.0, 0.0))
var tmpQ = PrimitiveDenseStore.FACTORY.rows(*Q)
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried that but still it seems that: `PrimitiveDenseStore.FACTORY.rows(Q)` with the line you wrote is not allowed as an argument.

Comment: Not an error but using InelliJ, the .rows() in `PrimitiveDenseStore.FACTORY.rows` is underline with red saying : "Non of the following functions can be called with the argument supplied"

Comment: And what are the "following functions"? :)

Comment: `rows(vararg (MutableList<out Number!>..List<Number!>?)) defined in org.ojalgo.matrix.store.PhysicalStore.Factory rows(vararg Array<(out) Number!>!) defined in org.ojalgo.matrix.store.PhysicalStore.Factory rows(vararg DoubleArray!) defined in org.ojalgo.matrix.store.PhysicalStore.Factory rows(vararg Access1D<*>!) defined in org.ojalgo.matrix.store.PhysicalStore.Factory`

Comment: So why would he accept the Java's double[][] and not Kotlin's??